# Trying to remove a literal in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone tell me what character this is in python as I am unable to remove it from the list.  I've split the list on the new line character and so I thought it was associated with that but I believe that splitting on something removes it from being in the list.  When I try to remove the characters using the literal presented to me in the list I've been unsuccessful.

[image]

Comment: [enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/cf5AFY6.png)

Comment: @ozgur Please don't encourage newbies to post images by inlining them. There's a reason why low-rep users can't inline images - they shouldn't be there in the first place.

Comment: So I try this the method that was listed in the flagged duplicate question but when I do this and print out the list I get None back.  I would add a picture but you seem to be opposed to that so...

Comment: We don't need to see a picture of `None`, we all know what that is. If anything, we need to see your code - and not as picture.

Comment: import string
string.punctuation


def open_file(f):
    with open(input("Enter a file name: "),'r' ) as inf:
        f = inf.read()
        return read_data(f)
    
def read_data(f):
      f = "".join(i for i in f if i not in string.punctuation)
        d = f.lower()
        d = d.strip()
        d = d.split('\n')
        print(d)

Comment: just filter the list from empty strings?

Comment: Perfect.  The one I looked at with that code did not have filter in it and I couldn't get it to work but when filter is applied it is exact.

thanks.

Comment: @NormandyAtomBryson if that solved your problem, I would suggest that you post that as an answer to your own question. That way others searching the web will find it..